# How to pass props between functions within a React component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-props

I'm looking to pass a prop to a component in the header of the navigation option.  Is there a way to pass `itemId` to `SaveButton` from within the component without using something like Context API or Redux?

```js
export default PostingDetail = ({ navigation }) => {
    const itemId = navigation.getParam('itemId', null)
    return (
        <SafeAreaView >
        </SafeAreaView>
    )
}

PostingDetail.navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
    title: "Posting Detail",
    headerRight: (
        <PleaseSignIn navigation={navigation} >        
            <SaveButton id={itemId} />
        </PleaseSignIn>
    )
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass param as below :

```js
export default PostingDetail = ({ navigation }) => {
    const itemId = navigation.getParam('itemId', null);
    navigation.setParams({ itemId }); // Pass itemId to navigation state
    return (
        <SafeAreaView >
        </SafeAreaView>
    )
}
```

And then you can get `itemId` as below :

```js
PostingDetail.navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
    title: "Posting Detail",
    headerRight: (
        <PleaseSignIn navigation={navigation} >        
            <SaveButton id={navigation.state.params.itemId} />
        </PleaseSignIn>
    )
})
```